# Can I use this piece (see pic) as a replacement?

Tags: electrical, hvac, furnace

[image]
[image]

Hi Guys,

I am on my last connection in my new mother board replacement for my Carrier furnace.  As I was trying to connect the wire in the top picture to the terminal it wouldn’t fit and the piggyback connecting the two wires nroke.  I don’t think these two wires are the same “gauge.” (Does that matter?)

My question is this:  can I buy this Amazon disconnect piece and connect each wire to it and then put it on the terminal?  Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: When you say not the same gauge what do you mean? Those spade connectors will handle a lot more than any 20 amp circuit can provide. After looking closer that wire is 16 awg so the 1/4" spade. With blue is medium. And it should be fine are you saying the blade is wider than the female?  I have had times where I have had to make slight adjustments like open the socket, I usually use a small flat blade screwdriver and a small pair of needle nose pliers to tighten them up once adjusted

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two female spade connectors and a female-to-female connector, and that's the part that broke.  The female-to-two-stacked-male connector you have pictured may work, you just wouldn't be using the female part of it.

I find that there are small differences between brands and things don't mate as well as they should.  If the wires are in good shape and not too short, a lot of times the easiest thing is to just cut off what's there and replace with your brand.

I don't see any compelling reason to use two female connectors here - I might replace these with one female and one male so you don't have the connector to deal with.  I'd also use the fully insulated connectors, just to be a little safer, less chance of accidental contact, shorts, etc., especially since it's line voltage.

You can connect these wires by any suitable means.  Crimp on connectors are easy to disconnect / reconnect without tools but you could use a wire nut, lever nut, etc. - anything listed and rated for the voltage and current.

Keep in mind that a lot of crimp terminal products are NOT listed / rated for line voltage, aimed more at the low voltage of the automotive market.  I stick to reputable manufacturers' brands.

Answer (score 0):

The one you have pictured is a bit different. When you say replacement that is one thing - when you say connect the two wires to it as a go between interconnect - that is another thing altogether (which is what you seem to be alluding to as the item pictured is not a replacement - it does not match the wire above.

Generally these spade type fittings are of the same sizes (there are for sure a few different standardized sizes and what you picture is pretty standard). That said a screw driver blade can twist between the rolled ends to widen the spade a little bit and also a twist in the insertion area can open the spade a bit - so that it will fit on the terminal.

You did not post a picture of your terminal connection on the new board (post one please) - so it is hard to tell what is going on. The above procedure should be sufficient , unless you have a really odd ball size.